# Gitlab-ci docker inside java image

Tags: java, docker, gitlab-ci

To use a integration test library [https://www.testcontainers.org/"](https://www.testcontainers.org/%22) I need a image with java a docker installed at same time.

I'm trying o use this stage:

```
test:
  stage: test
  image: gradle:jdk16
  services:
    - docker:latest
  script:
    - docker --version
    - chmod +x ./gradlew
    - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle
    - ./gradlew test  --stacktrace
  rules:
    - !reference [.rules_merge_request, rules]
```

But It does not work:

```
$ docker --version
/scripts-33119345-2089057982/step_script: line 154: docker: command not found
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally realized that our gitlab runner had locked the docker-in-docker so we couldn't start testcontainer for aur test in gitlab. Our solution was to use the kafka a postresql services provided by gitlab:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/

Answer (score 1):

The image `gradle:jdk16` does not include the docker client. You'll have to install it in your job. Additionally, you'll need to use the service `docker:dind` in your `services:` configuration (not `docker:latest`)

```yaml
test:
  stage: test
  image: gradle:jdk16
  services:
    - docker:dind # use the docker-in-docker image
  before_script: # install docker
    - apt update && apt install --no-install-recommends -y docker.io  
  script:
    - docker --version
```

Running this on gitlab.com runners, you should see an output like this:

[image: job on gitlab.com]

Comment: Thanks, it works but I get this error: " unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/docker not found." so if I run "service docker status" system returns me the error "docker: unrecognized service". Any recommendation?

Comment: @Rafael the docker daemon runs on the remote `docker:dind` service, not locally. So it won't be found in init.d or running services. You only need the docker _client_ not the docker _daemon_.

Comment: @sytech I have a similar issue as @Rafael ., I see an error `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`  when i would like to build a docker image.  docker -version is giving the response though.

Comment: added the /var/run/docker.sock` to the volumes section under [runners.docker]  in `config.toml`  to fix the issue, Reference :   `volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/certs/client", "/cache"]`

Comment: Hi @Niranjan, in our case we finally realized that out gitlab runner has locked the docker-in-docker so we couldn't start testcontainer for aur test in gitlab. 

Our solution was to use the kafka a postresql services provided by gitlab: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/